# Using Chromecast SDK to determine if closed captions are enabled on the receiver for android

Tags: android, chromecast

I would like to be able to determine if my receiver (CAF receiver) has captions being displayed. This will be so that I can rely on the receiver to tell the sender that captions are enabled, rather than saving the previous state of closed captions on the sender. Is there a method or a way of doing this using the remoteMediaClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm uncertain if you  mean the sender or receiver, but I'll give you both :)

It is possible to get it on Android like so

```
  private val SUB_TITLE_TYPES = intArrayOf(MediaTrack.SUBTYPE_SUBTITLES, MediaTrack.SUBTYPE_CAPTIONS)

 fun getActiveMediaTracks(context: Context): LongArray =
    getRemoteMediaClient(context)?.mediaStatus?.activeTrackIds ?: longArrayOf()

 fun getSubtitleTracks(context: Context): List<MediaTrack> =
    getActiveMediaTracks(context).filter {
        it.type == MediaTrack.TYPE_TEXT && it.subtype in SUB_TITLE_TYPES
    }
```

or on the Chromecast Receiver ([TextTracksManager](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/caf_receiver/cast.framework.TextTracksManager.html#getActiveTracks))

```
cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance().getTextTracksManager().getActiveTracks()
```

**EDIT**:
*Can see that I mixed up the two functions when I copied the code from our IDE. There are active ids and all media tracks (this includes audio, video, texts). There might be a difference between `MediaTrack.SUBTYPE_SUBTITLES*`, guess that depends on the stream.*

Heres how to find the active text tracks

```
val remoteMediaClient = CastContext.getSharedInstance(context).sessionManager?.currentCastSession?.remoteMediaClient
remoteMediaClient?.mediaInfo?.mediaTracks?.filter {
  it.type == MediaTrack.TYPE_TEXT && it.subtype in SUB_TITLE_TYPES
}?.let { 
  textTracks -> 
  val activeTrackIds = remoteMediaClient.mediaStatus?.activeTrackIds?.filter { activeTrackId ->
     textTracks.none { track -> track.id == activeTrackId }
  }.toLongArray()
 activeTrackIds.size > 0
}
```

Comment: I am assuming if activeTracks come back as null or 0, then there are no captions enabled, correct?

Comment: Yeah we use the same assumption.